# Passing values by pointer

Tags: c, pointers

```
29: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘*’ token
29: error: conflicting types for ‘kill’
/usr/include/signal.h:126: note: previous declaration of ‘kill’ was here

In function ‘kill’:
32: error: too many arguments to function ‘kill’
36: error: too many arguments to function ‘kill’
```

I am new to C, and having difficulties passing values from my main function to the kill functions below. This code is intended to be ran in a linux environment. The purpose is to open a pid file, grab the pid number, and pass the pid number to the kill functions to be tested if still valid. The code "was" running, but the value was not being passed to kill and was only successfully when an invalid argument (bad pid file name) was passed to the if statement. I attempted to use a pointer to pass the value, but cant seem to get it working. Any advice is appreciated.

tl;dr?
I cannot pass a value by pointer to a function.

```
#include <stdio.h>    //Needed for standard I/O
#include <stdlib.h>   //Needed for exit
#include <signal.h>   //Needed for kill function

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *pf;
    char pidvar;
    char *pidnum;

    pidnum = &pidvar;

    pf = fopen(argv[1], "r");

    if (pf == NULL){
        printf("Pid file doesn't exist\n");
        return 2;
    }
    else {
        do  {*pidnum = getc(pf);         /* get one character from the file */
            }while (*pidnum != EOF);     /* repeat until EOF (end of file) */
            fclose(pf);                 /* Close pidfile */
         }
}

    char *pidnum;

pid_t kill(*pidnum, int sig)         /* function declaration */
{

    if ((kill (*pidnum, 0)) == -1){
         printf("The pid %s is no longer valid", *pidnum);
         return 2;
    }
    else if ((kill (*pidnum, 0)) == 0){
         printf("The pid %s is valid", *pidnum);
         return 0;
    }
}                                                                1,1           Top
```

Comment: @Brian thank you, that is correct. I changed the function back to pid_t kill(pid_t *pidnum, int sig)    I assume, I must change the array to be declared as a pid_t type.

Answer (score 2):

> `note: previous declaration of ‘kill’ was here`

This is the compiler telling you that the function you wrote called "`kill`" is identically named with the function the system provides.  Note that your function calls `kill` also, and if there were no compiler error (if the system function had a different name) your function would just recurse on itself.

Give your function a new name.